# css float error, element doesn't float adjacent to the div preceding

Tags: html, css

i want to float a div exactly besides the other div. but unable to achieve that, there's a blank space between two divs and also float doesn't get the way i want to.

https://jsbin.com/fevuteseja/edit?html,css

What i want to do is, make the right div float exactly adjacent to the div ending before it and also starts at same level

```css
body, div, h1, span, code, p, mark, em, ul, li {margin:0px; padding:0px}
            body {background-color:slategray}
            .topnav {height:30px;}
            .topnav ul{
                list-style-type:none;
                background-color:#404040; 
                height:30px;
            }
            .topnav ul li {float:left;}
            .topnav ul li a {
                  display:block;
                  color:white;
                  text-decoration:none;
                  padding:6px 15px 4px;
                  font-family:calibri;
                  font-size:13px;
                  height:20px;
            }
            .topnav ul li a:hover {background-color:#3399ff}/*background-color:black;*/
            .sidenav {width:12%;position:fixed;height:100%;}
            .sidenav ul {
                list-style-type:none; 
                width:12%;height:100%;position:fixed;
                background-color:#f2f2f2;
            }
            .sidenav ul li a{
                display:block;
                padding: 5px 0px 5px 15px;
                text-decoration:none;
                color:black;
                font-family:calibri;
                font-size:11.0px;
                letter-spacing: 1.5px
            }
            .sidenav li a:hover:not(.active) {
                background-color:#bfbfbf; 
                color:white
            }
            .sidenav ul li a.active {
                background-color:#3399ff; 
                color:white;
            }
            .sidenav_heading {display:block; padding:5px 5px; margin:2px; font-family:calibri}
            .blank{margin-left:12%;height:15px;background-color: aqa}
            .container-main{font-family:calibri; margin-left:12%; display:inline-block; width:550px;padding-bottom:20px;background-color:hotpink}
            .container-main h1{width:530px;margin-bottom:15px;margin-left:20px;background-color: chartreuse}
            .container-main-block{margin-left:20px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;border-left:3px solid #339cff;background-color:#e6f3ff}
            .container-main p{width:500px;padding-left:12px;}
            mark {background-color:#99b3ff;color:white}
            .container-example{background-color:blue;display:inline-block;margin-top:0px;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webden</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html, charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="topnav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sidenav">
            <ul>
                <span class="sidenav_heading">CSS Tag Reference</span>
                <li><a href="1.html" class="active">Background</a></li>
                <li><a href="2.html ">Borders</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Color</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="blank"></div>
        <div class="container-main">
            <h1>CSS Backgrounds</h1>
            <div class="container-main-block">
            <p>Background property helps to achieve control over the background properties of any element in HTML.</p>
            <p><mark><em>background:</em></mark> is a shorthand property, that can be used as shown besides.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-example">
                <h1>background-color:red</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have several divs on your layout (and a blue div with content 'background red' let it even more confusing). Please be clear and tell us what are the name/color of the divs that you want to place.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
.container-main {
    background-color: hotpink;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-family: calibri;
    margin-left: 12%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 550px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following div from your html and it will float the way you want.

```
<div class="blank"></div>
```